# How to use after_stat on all fill aesthetic to one scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use the `after_stat(ndensity)` to scale to a maximum of 1 like described [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html#computed-variables):

> after_stat(ndensity) density, scaled to a maximum of 1.

When we use this with a `fill` aesthetic it of course scales each `fill` separately, but I was wondering if it possible to use `after_stat` to scale the complete data so all `fill` densities combined. Here is some reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_density(aes(y = after_stat(ndensity)), alpha = 0.4)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As expected the densities are scaled to all a maximum of 1. But I was wondering if anyone knows how to scales the combined, while having the three densities separately. This would result in only one density curve with a maximum value of 1. We could use `ggplot_build` to modify the layer, but I was wondering if there is an `after_stat` only option?

Comment: Do you mean have the densities stacked, so that the stacked densities sum to a maximum of 1, or have three unstacked densities, the largest of which has a density of 1?

Comment: Hi @AllanCameron, Your first answer works perfect, thank you very much again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the desired output correctly. If you want the peak density of the highest curve to equal one, and the others to be shown in relative terms, we can precalculate the peak density and divide `after_stat(density)` by it:

```r
library(tidyverse)

div <- iris %>%
  summarize(max = max(density(Sepal.Length)$y), .by = Species) %>%
  pull(max) %>%
  max()

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_density(aes(y = after_stat(density/div)), alpha = 0.4)
```

[image]

If you want the curves stacked with a peak total density of 1, then you could do:

```r
div <- iris %>%
  reframe(dens = density(Sepal.Length, 
                         from = min(iris$Sepal.Length),
                         to = max(iris$Sepal.Length))$y, 
          xval = seq(min(iris$Sepal.Length), max(iris$Sepal.Length), len = 512), 
          .by = Species) %>%
  group_by(xval) %>%
  summarize(dens = sum(dens)) %>%
  slice_max(order_by = dens, n = 1) %>%
  pull(dens)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_density(aes(y = after_stat(density/div)), position = 'stack', alpha = 0.4)
```

[image]